# Content-Type of each URLVariable in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to send some string variables as well as binary data inside one URLRequest in as3. This is what I'm doing

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

requestVars.nm = p_name;
requestVars.pw = pw;
requestVars.em = email;
requestVars.md5 = MD5.hashBinary(sqlite);
requestVars.sqlite = sqlite;

request.contentType = "application/octet-stream";
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = requestVars;

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completionHandler);
urlLoader.load(request);
```

It gives me I/O Error on server.

> [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: `http://localhost:8086/reg/`" errorID=2032]

Is it the right way to send this? Can we send Content-Type of each URLVariable in as3? 
Also I'm losing my email and other string param because of its in binary.